# Managing Nexus repository groups

Tags: nexus

I want to proxy the Eclipse ELK updatesites in my Nexus 2.14.4-03. I created four different proxy repositories for versions 0.1.0, 0.1.1, 0.2.0 and 0.2.1.

Then I created a Repository Group called Eclipse_ELK
[image]

Knowing that the order of the repositories matter, I placed 0.1.0 at the top. But when I use Eclipse->Help->Install New Software and mention the URL of the group repository, I am getting 0.2.0 to install. Why is this so?

[image]

Comment: A couple questions: are you proxying the maven repos for each? AKA: http://build.eclipse.org/modeling/elk/maven/meta/ (you might want to add those URLs to your original question, it's not immediately apparent which you are using). Second is if you aren't, I think these are P2 repositories, so I'd go ahead and check that out, too. Let me know, game to help! ~Sonatype Community Nerd

Comment: @DarthHater, I am using P2 remote sites - http://download.eclipse.org/elk/updates/releases/0.X.Y for mirroring each of the proxy repositories mentioned in my question.